# Python-Selenium : Not able to scrape image from html/javascript string

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I have one HTML string which I am opening in browser from PhanthomJs and trying to save the outcome URL.

My code looks as below.

```
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))
element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
elem =  element.find_element_by_tag_name('noscript')
print elem.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
```

The `html_content` look like below.

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://somejs"></script>
<noscript>
<a href="https://track.adform.net/C/?bn=15864640;C=0" target="_blank">
<img src="https://actualimage.net/verbserve/?bn=155679864640;srctype=4;ord=[timestamp]" border="0" width="728" height="90" alt=""/>
</a>
</noscript>
```

Above html render an image when I ran it locally as html file.

I wanted to save that image with the code I have mentioned above. But unfortunately I am not able to find the img using `find_element_by_tag_name`

I am getting below error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with tag name 'img'","request"
```

Please let me know what might I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if simple HTML content not web page content

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_content = """ <script language="javascript" src="https://somejs"></script>
<noscript>
<a href="https://track.adform.net/C/?bn=15864640;C=0" target="_blank">
<img src="https://actualimage.net/verbserve/?bn=155679864640;srctype=4;ord=[timestamp]" border="0" width="728" height="90" alt=""/>
</a>
</noscript>""" 


sp = BeautifulSoup(html_content,'html.parser')

elem =  sp.find('noscript')

img = elem.find('img') 
print(img['src'])
```

O/P:

[https://actualimage.net/verbserve/?bn=155679864640;srctype=4;ord=[timestamp]](https://actualimage.net/verbserve/?bn=155679864640;srctype=4;ord=%5Btimestamp%5D)

**scrape** web page content by website url:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.get('http://www.test.com')

sp = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')

elem =  sp.find('noscript')

img = elem.find('img') 
print(img['src'])
```

Where `"/usr/bin/chromedriver"` chrome drive path